# Como validar um token?

Tags: javascript, laravel, react, passport-js

Tenho uma api em laravel passport, no meu front end que é em react eu criei uma rota privada, nessa rota privada eu chamei uma função checkAuth, pra saber de o usuário ta autenticado, mas por enquanto fiz essa função passando so true ou false pra testar, como sou iniciante, quando tentei verificar se o token é verdadeiro ou não, acabei travando, pois não sei como fazer e nem por onde começar, precisaria de um exemplo prático, se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Até a parte de verificar usuário e senha, gerar o token e armazenar ele no local storage ta ok. Só preciso verificar se esse token é verdadeiro ou se não foi alterado, obrigado desde já!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [React: Verificar usuário autenticado pelo front-end!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398748/react-verificar-usu%c3%a1rio-autenticado-pelo-front-end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa validar ele, se sua rota privada estiver dentro do middleware de autenticação do passport ele já validará automaticamente para você, você não precisa ficar realizando estas checagens.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    // rotas que serão validadas e só passarão se vc tiver logado com token válido
    Route::get('user', 'PassportController@details');
});
```

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13

Comment: Obrigado mano <3